# Drinfeld's "almost cocommutative Hopf algebras"

Tags: reference-request, quantum-groups

I'm looking for the following paper (in English):

> Drinfelʹd, V. G. Almost cocommutative Hopf algebras. Leningrad Math. J. 1
> (1990), no. 2, 321–342

I can only find the russian version on the internet (Algebra i Analiz 1 (1989), no. 2, 30–46).

There are (freely) available archives for Leningrad Math. J. (that became St. Peter. Math. J.) on the AMS website, but they only start from 2004.

Comment: How confident are you that a translation exists?

Comment: It was published in Russian in Algebra i Analiz in 1989, and translated in English in 1990 (the translation appeared in Leningrad Math. J.). 
On Mathscinet it appears as follows: 
Drinfelʹd, V. G. Almost cocommutative Hopf algebras. (Russian) Algebra i Analiz 1 (1989), no. 2, 30–46; translation in Leningrad Math. J. 1 (1990), no. 2, 321–342